# trigger statement in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am a begineer in asp.net , I am creating a login form which access a database to validate user account. I have used basic SQL queries (select with where clause) to validate the account , is it possible to use Trigger Statement ?

Comment: Don't try an recreate the wheel.   This sounds like some basic database authentication.  ASP.Net Membership will handle what you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use trigger to validate an account. Actually a trigger is like a stored procedure that automatically executes when an event (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE) occurs in the database server.

To know more about trigger, check this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: I'm developing a ecommerce module , so I can use trigger when inserting a product details to a table right ?

Comment: Yes, you can use triggers when you fire insert/update/delete events.